Oracle hierarchical query joining 2 tables
I have 2 tables: projects and tasks (that's a simplification, but will do for now). PROJECTS has a hierarchy of projects where there can be a detached (standalone) project or a projects hierarchy. TASKS contains a list of tasks. Tasks are hierarchical in nature and are linked to projects. In case of the projects hierarchy, tasks in the top level are kind of templates and can be redefined in the lower level projects (in my case, i have a hierarchy of 2 projects). That is, i want:

Determine the top-level project starting with the lowest level execution project
Starting from the top-level project, display hierarchy of tasks that will show the lowest project level for identical task IDs.

Sample table structure:
create table projects
( project_id varchar(14)
, parent_project_id varchar(14));

create table tasks
( project_id varchar(14)
, task_id varchar(6)
, parent_task_id varchar(6)
, inactive char(1)
, redefined char(1)
);

Sample data:
PROJECTS:



PROJECT_ID
PARENT_PROJECT_ID




MASTER_PROJECT
' '


EXECUTION_PROJ
MASTER_PROJECT


UNRELATED_PROJ
' '



TASKS:



PROJECT_ID
TASK_ID
PARENT_TASK_ID
INACTIVE
REDEFINED




EXECUTION_PROJ
101000
100000
X
X


EXECUTION_PROJ
101010
101000
X



EXECUTION_PROJ
101011
101010
X



EXECUTION_PROJ
101012
101010




EXECUTION_PROJ
102000
100000

X


EXECUTION_PROJ
102010
102000




EXECUTION_PROJ
102011
102010




EXECUTION_PROJ
210000
200000




EXECUTION_PROJ
300000
000000

X


EXECUTION_PROJ
310000
000000
X
X


MASTER_PROJECT
100000
000000




MASTER_PROJECT
101000
100000




MASTER_PROJECT
102000
100000
X



MASTER_PROJECT
200000
000000




MASTER_PROJECT
300000
000000




MASTER_PROJECT
310000
300000





I can determine the top-level project easily (or i can hardcode it, doesn't matter); and i can show hierarchy of tasks, that also works fine (sorry, working in the ABAP environment, can't create Oracle tables; trying to emulate this with select from dual):
with projects as (
select 'MASTER_PROJECT' project_id, ' ' parent_project_id from dual
union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', 'MASTER_PROJECT' from dual
union all
select 'UNRELATED_PROJ', ' ' from dual),

toplvl_proj as (
select project_id from projects
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by prior parent_project_id = project_id
start with project_id = 'EXECUTION_PROJ'),

tasks(PROJECT_ID, TASK_ID, PARENT_TASK_ID, INACTIVE, REDEFINED) as (
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '101000', '100000', 'X', 'X' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '101010', '101000', 'X', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '101011', '101010', 'X', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '101012', '101010', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '102000', '100000', ' ', 'X' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '102010', '102000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '102011', '102010', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '210000', '200000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '300000', '000000', ' ', 'X' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '310000', '000000', 'X', 'X' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '100000', '000000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '101000', '100000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '102000', '100000', 'X', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '200000', '000000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '300000', '000000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '310000', '300000', ' ', ' ' from dual)

select t.*, p.parent_project_id, level tsklvl
from tasks t
join projects p on p.project_id = t.project_id
connect by prior t.task_id = t.parent_task_id
start with t.project_id in (select project_id from toplvl_proj)
and t.parent_task_id = '000000'

SQL Fiddle
What i don't understand is how to leave only the lowest level (from the task_id perspective) - that is, if a task exists only in the parent project or only in the execution project, select it; if it exists in both projects, select only the record belonging to the execution project.
The above query produces this result:



PROJECT_ID
TASK_ID
PARENT_TASK_ID
INACTIVE
REDEFINED
PARENT_PROJECT_ID
TSKLVL




MASTER_PROJECT
100000
000000



1


EXECUTION_PROJ
101000
100000
X
X
MASTER_PROJECT
2


EXECUTION_PROJ
101010
101000
X

MASTER_PROJECT
3


EXECUTION_PROJ
101011
101010
X

MASTER_PROJECT
4


EXECUTION_PROJ
101012
101010


MASTER_PROJECT
4


MASTER_PROJECT
101000
100000



2


EXECUTION_PROJ
101010
101000
X

MASTER_PROJECT
3


EXECUTION_PROJ
101011
101010
X

MASTER_PROJECT
4


EXECUTION_PROJ
101012
101010


MASTER_PROJECT
4


EXECUTION_PROJ
102000
100000

X
MASTER_PROJECT
2


EXECUTION_PROJ
102010
102000


MASTER_PROJECT
3


EXECUTION_PROJ
102011
102010


MASTER_PROJECT
4


MASTER_PROJECT
102000
100000
X


2


EXECUTION_PROJ
102010
102000


MASTER_PROJECT
3


EXECUTION_PROJ
102011
102010


MASTER_PROJECT
4


MASTER_PROJECT
200000
000000



1


EXECUTION_PROJ
210000
200000


MASTER_PROJECT
2


MASTER_PROJECT
300000
000000



1


MASTER_PROJECT
310000
300000



2



What i need is this (duplicate blocks removed, tasks starting with 3* show EXECUTION_PROJ instead of MASTER_PROJECT and respective values in REDEFINED and INACTIVE fields):



PROJECT_ID
TASK_ID
PARENT_TASK_ID
INACTIVE
REDEFINED
PARENT_PROJECT_ID
TSKLVL




MASTER_PROJECT
100000
000000



1


EXECUTION_PROJ
101000
100000
X
X
MASTER_PROJECT
2


EXECUTION_PROJ
101010
101000
X

MASTER_PROJECT
3


EXECUTION_PROJ
101011
101010
X

MASTER_PROJECT
4


EXECUTION_PROJ
101012
101010


MASTER_PROJECT
4


EXECUTION_PROJ
102000
100000

X
MASTER_PROJECT
2


EXECUTION_PROJ
102010
102000


MASTER_PROJECT
3


EXECUTION_PROJ
102011
102010


MASTER_PROJECT
4


MASTER_PROJECT
200000
000000



1


EXECUTION_PROJ
210000
200000


MASTER_PROJECT
2


EXECUTION_PROJ
300000
000000



1


EXECUTION_PROJ
310000
300000



2



Can this be achieved?

Silly me. ROW_NUMBER() allows to get rid of unnecessary duplicates, and then hierarchical query doesn't need to worry about cross-project connections:
with projects as (
select 'MASTER_PROJECT' project_id, ' ' parent_project_id from dual
union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', 'MASTER_PROJECT' from dual
union all
select 'UNRELATED_PROJ', ' ' from dual),

proj_hier as (
select project_id, level proj_level from projects
connect by parent_project_id = prior project_id 
start with project_id = 'MASTER_PROJECT'),

tasks(PROJECT_ID, TASK_ID, PARENT_TASK_ID, INACTIVE, REDEFINED) as (
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '101000', '100000', 'X', 'X' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '101010', '101000', 'X', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '101011', '101010', 'X', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '101012', '101010', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '102000', '100000', ' ', 'X' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '102010', '102000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '102011', '102010', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '210000', '200000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '300000', '000000', ' ', 'X' from dual union all
select 'EXECUTION_PROJ', '310000', '000000', 'X', 'X' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '100000', '000000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '101000', '100000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '102000', '100000', 'X', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '200000', '000000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '300000', '000000', ' ', ' ' from dual union all
select 'MASTER_PROJECT', '310000', '300000', ' ', ' ' from dual),

proj_tasks as (
select t.*, ph.proj_level,
       row_number() over(partition by t.task_id order by ph.proj_level desc) rn
from tasks t
join proj_hier ph on t.project_id = ph.project_id)


select t.*, level task_level from proj_tasks t
where rn = 1
connect by prior task_id = parent_task_id
start with parent_task_id = '000000'

Sorry... it took me the whole day and a post to StackOverflow to realise what the solution should look like...

Another (unpleasant) surprise was to discover that SQL Fiddle doesn't support CTEs... At least, it didn't for me, or i'm unaware of the correct syntax of block delimiters (/ and ;).

Added a correct version of the query to SQL Fiddle (which doesn't contain CTEs though...)
